# Odd point issue by null pointer

Tags: c, bsearch

I am doing a code practice using C language.

As below codes,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

int ACDSort(const void *p1, const void *p2);
int Compare(const void *pKey, const void *pValue);
int main(void)
{
    char * strAry[4] = {"Hardware","Cookie","Boy","Power"};
    char * destStr = "Cookie";

    //qsort((void*)strAry, sizeof(strAry) / sizeof(char*), sizeof(char*), ACDSort);

    char **ptrAdr = (char**)bsearch((void*)destStr, strAry, sizeof(strAry) / sizeof(char*), sizeof(char*), Compare);

    printf("%s\n", *ptrAdr);
}

int Compare(const void *pKey, const void *pValue) {
    char *key = ((char*)pKey);
    char *value = *((char**)pValue);
    return strcmp(key, value);
}

int ACDSort(const void *p1, const void *p2) {

    char * n1 = *((char**)p1);
    char * n2 = *((char**)p2);
    int ret;

    if (strlen(n1) > strlen(n2))
        ret = 1;
    else if (strlen(n1) < strlen(n2))
        ret = -1;
    else
        ret = 0;
    return ret;
}
```

I called `bsearch` to find the string of `cookie`.
The problem is that the error occurred when I erased the `//` in order to sort the array based on the string length.
I don't know why the error was executed because I think that `qsort` couldn't be able to significant affect to my codes.

Could you tell me the reason why the error occurred returning null pointer when erasing the `//`?

Ps. I used `qsort` and `bsearch` to get familiar with pointer variables.

Comment: `bsearch` only works if the array is already sorted

Comment: Note that you should normally use the same comparison function for both `qsort()` and `bsearch()`.  You're doing something wrong if you must use different functions.

Comment: Why use different functions for both `qsort()` and `bsearch()`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Not in this case. See the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bsearch` uses binary search, that's why. Binary search requires the data to be sorted. Sort the string array in alphabetic order and it will work.

As a side note, you need to get rid of all those superfluous casts, all they do is to hide potential bugs.

Working program after fixes and clean-up:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int compare (const void* p1, const void* p2);

int main (void)
{
    const char* strAry[4] = {"Boy", "Cookie", "Hardware", "Power"};
    const char* key = "Cookie";

    char** ptrAdr = bsearch(key, 
                            strAry, 
                            sizeof(strAry)/sizeof(*strAry), 
                            sizeof(*strAry), 
                            compare);

    printf("%s\n", *ptrAdr);
}

int compare (const void* p1, const void* p2) 
{
  const char* s1 = p1;
  const char* s2 = *(const char* const*)p2;

  return strcmp(s1, s2);
}
```

p2 will end up a `const` void pointer to a `const char*`, which is why we get that weird-looking cast when striving for const-correctness.

Answer (score -1):

Type of `destStr` can be changed to be the same as type of `strAry`, e.g.:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int Compare(const void *pKey, const void *pValue)
{
    char *key = *((char**)pKey);
    char *value = *((char**)pValue);
    return strcmp(key, value);
}

int main(void)
{
    char * strAry[4] = { "Hardware", "Cookie", "Boy", "Power" };
    char * destStr[1] = { "Cookie" }; // Type changing

    qsort(strAry, sizeof(strAry) / sizeof(char*), sizeof(char*), Compare);

    char **ptrAdr = (char**)bsearch((void*)destStr, strAry, sizeof(strAry) / sizeof(char*), sizeof(char*), Compare);

    printf("%s\n", *ptrAdr);
}
```

Also, if you use C language (and compiler) consider using `strcmp` directly as callback function that compares two elements.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*int Compare(const void *pKey, const void *pValue)
{
    char *key = *((char**)pKey);
    char *value = *((char**)pValue);
    return strcmp(key, value);
}*/

int main(void)
{
    char * strAry[4] = { "Hardware", "Cookie", "Boy", "Power" };
    char * destStr[1] = { "Cookie" }; // Type changing

    //qsort(strAry, sizeof(strAry) / sizeof(char*), sizeof(char*), Compare);
    qsort(strAry, sizeof(strAry) / sizeof(char*), sizeof(char*), strcmp);

    //char **ptrAdr = (char**)bsearch((void*)destStr, strAry, sizeof(strAry) / sizeof(char*), sizeof(char*), Compare);
    char **ptrAdr = (char**)bsearch(destStr, strAry, sizeof(strAry) / sizeof(char*), sizeof(char*), strcmp);

    printf("%s\n", *ptrAdr);
}
```

**Note:**

This solution has one disadvantage that appears as ...

> warning: passing argument 5 of ‘bsearch’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

But it works (I have tried with GCC version 4.8.2 and MS Visual studio 12.0)

Comment: It might work when testing, but it's still illegal as compiler is trying to tell you. There is no need to introduce possible problems when simple wrapper would fix it. Because of undefined behaviour in C, you can never use just testing to determine if something is ok.

Comment: Yes, that is like a trick.... so, I leave commented code that can be used instead.

Comment: Pointer conversion from `int (*)(const char*)(const char*)` to `int (*)(const void*)(const void*)` invokes undefined behavior. It will "work" by luck in case there happen to be no calling convention differences between the two, in case `void*` and `char*` has the same representation and in case there are no pointer aliasing optimizations in the code.